# What is wrong with this SQL query from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

The following code keeps giving me error messages from the database. Does anyone know what is wrong with it? Thanks in advance!

```
<?php 
$host = "***host***";
$database = "***database***";
$user = "***dbuser***";
$password = "***password***";
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo "Fail:" . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE 'Username' = $_POST[uname];";
echo $_POST[uname];
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
die('Error' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo 'Added';
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I don't see why HTML is relevant. And why not narrow down the problem to _either_ PHP or MySQL? What are the errors?

Comment: I guess wrong credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate cause is

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE 'Username' = $_POST[uname];";
```

which should be

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = '" . $_POST['uname'] . "'";
```

Ie, not ; and quote the string value and the array index in the POST array, but not around the fieldname.

However, you should ***never ever*** just plop received values into an SQL statement that opens your code up to all kinds of problems, most importantly SQL Injection.  Go to [this site](http://bobby-tables.com/) to learn about SQL injection, and what to do about it.

Answer (score 1):

replace this line

$sql="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE 'Username' = $_POST[uname];";

with this one

$sql="SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = '$_POST[uname]';";

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST[uname]` is probably a string, so you'll need it to be quote-delimited in your query.

But, then, you should *never* be writing user input directly into a query. And you should be using prepared statements.

Further, table/field names are encased in *backticks*, not quotations or apostrophes. That is:

```
`Username`
```

not

```
'Username'
```

Comment: @zerkms: Yes, I'm well aware.

Comment: @zerkms Brilliant. Well my answer is not the place to teach them every case. Write a book!

Comment: @zerkms: Because your advice is subjective. It is not wildly dangerous to ever put string input directly into a query, no matter how much you may advise avoiding it. It entirely depends on where the data comes from and how much you know about it, as to how important it is to wave your hands about and shout about it. On the other hand, using unsanitised user input is patently a security flaw no matter what else you do, and I did not need to go any further than that for the purposes of this Q&A. You can't save all the newbies.

Comment: @zerkms: I refuse to let you dictate the conditions of what **I** write in my code. You do not have that right.

Comment: @zerkms What are you talking about? I know how to write valid syntax, and I have the experience to know when explicit sanitising is necessary and when it's a waste of cycles given some known input. Stop being so arrogant.

Comment: PS: indeed may be I was too expressive this time, I'm just so upset of people around who only mention only user input and this leads to further issues when newbies follow the advice blindly. Sorry